# Can I deserialize to a class and have extra JSON properties go into a JObject on that class?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Let's assume we have the following JSON:

```
{ 
    "a": 10,
    "b": "foo",
    "c": 30,
    "d": "bar",
}
```

and the C# class:

```
class Stuff 
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public JObject Others { get; set; }
}
```

Is there an easy way to make the deserialization of the JSON above populate members `A` and `B` with the values of `a` and `b` and put the values of `c` and `d` as JProperties in the `Others` JObject?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deserialize json with known and unknown fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253875/deserialize-json-with-known-and-unknown-fields)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this easily using Json.Net's "extension data" feature.  You just need to mark your `Others` property with a `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute and it should work the way you want.

```
class Stuff 
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public JObject Others { get; set; }
}
```

Demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"
        { 
            ""a"": 10,
            ""b"": ""foo"",
            ""c"": 30,
            ""d"": ""bar"",
        }";

        var stuff = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stuff>(json);

        Console.WriteLine(stuff.A);
        Console.WriteLine(stuff.B);
        Console.WriteLine(stuff.Others["c"]);
        Console.WriteLine(stuff.Others["d"]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
10
foo
30
bar
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6UVvFI

Answer (score 1):

You would need to implement a [JsonConverter](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/AllMembers_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) for this. It provides full flexibility in terms of custom deserialization.

Implement your [ReadJson](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm) method to traverse the input JSON using JsonReader and map its values to appropriate destination properties.

See [here](http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/) for full example.

Comment: You have my +1 for the good answer. You may still turn this into an excelent answer if you include an example in the question itself - sometimes links get broken (when the external content ceases existing), but examples within the answer itself are always timeless.

Comment: Thanks, actually I discovered that there is a solution and implementation already [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253875/deserialize-json-with-known-and-unknown-fields/15255330#15255330), so I marked this question as duplicate.