# How to deserialize root object with meaningless dynamic key names? Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am getting the following from json payload from a REST request.

```
{
    "version": "1.1", 
    "date": "2017-01-06",
    "count": "130",
    "0": {
          "artist": "Artist 1",
          "title": "Title 1"
     },
    "1": {
          "artist": "Artist 2",
          "title": "Title 2"
     },
    ...
    "49": {
          "artist": "Artist 50",
          "title": "Title 50"
     }
}
```

As you can see, there are several numeric root elements.  These elements index the object in the response, so I don't need the numbers themselves, I just need the `Song` object they represent.  I also need `count` to know if I need to make a call to the server to get the next page of songs (the server returns 50 `Song` objects max per call).

Here is what I have for `Song` class:

```
public class Song
{
    public string artist {get; set;}
    public string title {get; set;}
}
```

But I am having issues getting the root element.  I tried to mimic the process used when there is a dynamic child element, but this does not work.

```
public class SongsResponse
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string count {get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Song> songs { get; set; }
}
```

I've seen solutions that "throw away" `version`, `date` and `count` and others that do it without pre-defined classes.

But I need `count` and ideally would want to work from predefined classes.

Comment: Down vote with no comment??

Comment: Is refactoring an option?  Why do you 'need' count? If `songs` implements `ICollection` it will have a `Count` property.

Comment: Server only returns 50 responses at a time.  But `count` tells you how many fit the criteria.  So `count` could be `250`.  Updated question to make that clearer.

Comment: So are the 'numbers as root elements' song ids or do they just represent the index of the song in the response body?

Comment: They merely index song within response body.

Comment: The schema you are describing would not work in a data paging scenario unless the 'numbers as root elements' have more meaning than the index of the song within the response.  Simply return 0 - 49 for every response does not give you enough information to determine that there are still more songs. They must represent a song id or the ordinal position of the song on the server.  In which case I would expect the next response to be something like 50 - 99.

Comment: You would think that...but that's not what I'm getting from the sever.  `page=2` also returns songs with indices 0-49 (even though they are 50 different songs than found on `page=1`).  Very poorly designed json responses, in my opinion.

Comment: Wow, that is awful!

Comment: Sounds like you want `[JsonTypedExtensionData]` and `[JsonConverter(typeof(TypedExtensionDataConverter<SongsResponse>))]` from [How to deserialize a child object with dynamic (numeric) key names?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40094403/3744182).  In fact, is that a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to include an index.  The songs are indexed by virtue of the fact that they will be deserialized to a collection.  Change your schema like so:

```
{  
   "version":"1.1",
   "date":"2017-01-06",
   "count":"130",
   "songs":[  
      {  
         "artist":"Artist 1",
         "title":"Title 1"
      },
      {  
         "artist":"Artist 2",
         "title":"Title 2"
      },
      {  
         "artist":"Artist 3",
         "title":"Title 3"
      }
   ]
}

public class Song
{
    public string artist {get; set;}
    public string title {get; set;}
}

public class SongsResponse
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string count {get; set; }
    public List<Song> songs { get; set; }
}
```

## Update

So you may have no control over the json being sent to you but you still have control over your local domain objects and how you deserialize the json.  I would stick with the class definitions I defined above and create a custom `JsonConverter` that you can use to deserialize the response into something that makes a little more sense.  Actually, while you are at it you can make your `SongsResponse` class 'better' by using the appropriate type for the `date` and `count` properties (why use a strongly typed language if you are not going to take advantage of it).

So this class:

```
public class SongsResponseJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanWrite is false. The type will skip the converter.");
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var result = new SongsResponse();

        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        result.version = obj["version"].Value<string>();
        result.date = obj["date"].Value<DateTime>();
        result.count = obj["count"].Value<int>();
        result.songs =
            obj
            .Properties()
            .Where(x => !(new string[] { "version", "date", "count" }.Contains(x.Name)))
            .Select(x => new { Id = int.Parse(x.Name), Song = x })
            .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
            .Select(x => x.Song.Value.ToObject<Song>())
            .ToList();
        return result;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(SongsResponse);
    }
}
```

Which you would use like this:

```
var json = @"
{
    ""version"": ""1.1"", 
    ""date"": ""2017-01-06"",
    ""count"": ""130"",
    ""0"": {
        ""artist"": ""Artist 1"",
          ""title"": ""Title 1""
     },
    ""1"": {
        ""artist"": ""Artist 2"",
          ""title"": ""Title 2""
     },
    ""49"": {
        ""artist"": ""Artist 50"",
          ""title"": ""Title 50""
     }
}";

var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SongsResponse>(json, new SongsResponseJsonConverter());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the schema.  This is a response given to me by a server outside of my control.

Comment: @JasonBoyd Your impression is wrong.. It is related with  answer.  `Change your schema like ....` is not answer.

Comment: @L.B Changing the schema is a perfectly valid answer if you have full control over it.  It happens that the OP does not in this case but that was not apparent until after my original answer.

Comment: Now, Move all codes in *ReadJson* out of class and it will work too. So you don't need *JsonConverter* with this code...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to deserialize constant part of the JSON using common ways and then construct dynamic part usin JSON2LINQ. In your particular case it looks like the following:

```
var json = JObject.Parse(responseString);

var response = json.ToObject<SongsResponse>();
response.songs = json.Properties().Where(t => Regex.Match(t.Name, "\\d+").Success).ToDictionary(t => t.Name, t => t.Value.ToObject<Song>());
```

NOTE: Under the hood Regex.Match caches regex object after the first call and all subsequent calls reuse that object.