# Deserializing Complex Json Contains dictionary with Fields in C# .Net core

Tags: json, .net, .net-core, json.net

I am getting below json for api.

```
{
  "performances": [
    {
      "Employee1": {
        "firstname": "xxx",
        "value": 2678       
      },
      "Employee2": {
        "firstname": "yyy",
        "value": 2676
       
      },
      "starttime": "2021-04-09T14:48:00Z",
      "endtime": "2022-04-09T14:49:00Z"
    },
    {
      "Employee1": {
        "firstname": "xxx",
        "value": 3354 
      },
      "Employee2": {
        "firstname": "yyy",
        "value": 234
      },
      "Employee3": {
        "firstname": "qqq",
        "value": 2344
      },
      "starttime": "2022-04-09T14:49:00Z",
      "endtime": "2023-04-09T14:50:00Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

tried Creating `Dictionary<string, employee>`.   but `starttime` and `endtime` gives the problem.

Can someone help me to Deserializing in .Net core using c#

i tried creating below classes. nothing worked. I was getting null for all values

```
public class Variable
    {
        public string firstname{ get; set; }
        public double value{ get; set; }
    }
    public class Custom
    {
        public List<Dictionary<string, Variable>> response { get; set; }
        public string starttime { get; set; }
        public string endtime { get; set; }
    }
    public class CustomerList
    {       
        public List<Custom> performances { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Use `[JsonExtensionData]` attribute

Comment: Since the values of your unknown-in-advance `Employee*` properties are typed as `Variable` rather than free-form JSON, possibly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40094403/3744182) to [How to deserialize a child object with dynamic (numeric) key names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40088941/3744182) does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `JsonExtensionData` and process it "dynamically":

Newtonsoft Json.NET:

```cs
foreach (var custom in customerList.performances.ToList())
{
    foreach (var kvp in custom.ExtensionData)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
        Console.WriteLine((kvp.Value as Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject).ToObject<Variable>().firstname);
    }
}

// the rest classes are the same
public class Custom
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JToken>? ExtensionData { get; set; }
    public string starttime { get; set; }
    public string endtime { get; set; }
}
```

`System.Text.Json`:

```cs
var customerList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CustomerList>(js1);

foreach (var custom in customerList.performances.ToList())
{
    foreach (var kvp in custom.ExtensionData)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value.Deserialize<Variable>().firstname);
    }
}

public class Custom
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JsonElement>? ExtensionData { get; set; }
    public string starttime { get; set; }
    public string endtime { get; set; }
}
```

Otherwise you will need to write a [custom converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) ([`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0)).

Comment: @Charlieface nothing. Closed as dupe.