# Which type should be a free json field in a DTO in C# dotnet core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I receive a free form JSON field, which I do not need to touch. My service simply saves it in a DB (the other fields are important, but this one has nothing to do with the logic. The client can put anything in it).

Example:

```
Body = {
    title: myTitle,
    stuff: {can be any json}
}
```

How should I map this to a DTO class?

Example:

```
public class MyDto(){
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ?????? Stuff { get; set; }
```

I tried using "string", but it does not work (the whole body is received as null, as it does not understand that it's the correct DTO type).
My current idea is to go with the "dynamic" type, would that be a good idea?

I'm looking for best practices.

Comment: you might be able to get away with `JsonExtensionData` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253875/deserialize-json-with-known-and-unknown-fields)

Comment: Depending on how your program will use that property, you may like to also consider "object" as an option

Answer (score 4):

You could use `dynamic` and the JSON.NET library:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/aug/30/using-jsonnet-for-dynamic-json-parsing

Comment: The dynamic type works, but it makes it difficult to use automapper, fluent validation and other packages that are not fully compatible with dynamic instructions. I also tried the object type, but it's difficult to manage (lots of casts).

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [System.Json.JsonElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Text.Json.JsonElement);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netcore-3.0) to represent a generic Json node as exemplified bellow.

```
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    public class InputDTO
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public System.Text.Json.JsonElement Stuff { get; set; }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public void Post([FromBody] InputDTO data)
    {
        var rawSuffJson = data.Stuff.ToString();
    }
}
```

The HTTP request body can be like this:

```
{
    "title": "My Title",
    "stuff": {
        "str": "String",
        "int32": 1,
        "list": [ 1,2,3 ]

    }
}
```

Comment: This only works in dotnet core 3, it's very restrictive. Still, I'm considering to update to try it.