# How to fetch data from Dictionary<string, dynamic> (Json DeserializeObject)

Tags: json, json.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have Deserialized dynamic Json using Newtonsoft.  The JSON is complex and dynamic.

```
{
"last_updated": " ",
"regions": {
"antarctica": {
        "name": "Antarctica",
        "totals": [],
        "list": [
            "aq",
            "bv",
            "gs",
            "tf",
            "hm"
        ]
    },
"world": {
        "name" : "",
        "totals": {
            "confirmed": 250566,
            "daily_confirmed": 0,
            "recovered": 202098,
            "deaths": 35205,
            "daily_deaths": 0,
            "critical": 676,
            "tests": 7249844
        },
        "list": [
            {
                "country": "Italy",
                "country_code": "it",
                "state": "Lombardy",
                "confirmed": 85775,
                "deaths": 15662,
                "critical": 231,
                "recovered": 231,
                "tests": 43442,
                "daily_confirmed": -1,
                "daily_deaths": -1
            }, and so on ..
```

To overcome the data type issue I have used the dynamic objects

```
        [JsonTypedExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, dynamic> items { get; set; }
```

Up to This works well. Now I am trying to fetch the data out of this dynamic Dictionary

```
var report = await GetCountryReport();
        Dictionary<string, dynamic> Dict = report.regions.results["world"].items;
```

I'm getting data as Dict Count (2)

```
[0] = {[list, {[ {"country": "Italy","confirmed": 4149,"deaths": 55,"recovered": 2916,"Incidence_Rate": "54.408517127144925","Case-Fatality_Ratio": "1.274822260357931","last_updated": "2020-08-10T22:30:32Z","...
[1] = {[totals, {{"confirmed": 20218306,"recovered": 12814226,"deaths": 737481,"critical": 64743,"tests": 370260493}}]}
```

How do I fetch the values of each element from the Dictionary like "values.list.country" etc..?

[Visual Studio debug - output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2MpM.png)

Comment: Are you using `JsonTypedExtensionData` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40094403/3744182)?  If so, it's not appropriate for use here, it's intended for situations when the unknown properties have a fixed schema.  Instead use the built-in attribute [`[JsonExtensionData]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonExtensionDataAttribute.htm) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21763919/3744182) to [Deserialize json with known and unknown fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15253875/3744182).

Comment: If you declare your items as `Dictionary<string, JToken>` rather than `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` your code will be statically checked for correctness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
var list = Dict.Where(x => x.Key == "list").Select(x => x.Value).SingleOrDefault();
var data = ((JArray)list).Select(x => new
{
    country = (string)x["country"],
    state = (string)x["state"],
    confirmed = (int)x["confirmed"]
    //...other properties in list
}).ToList();
```

The data structure is like below:

[image]

Then, you can use a foreach loop to get the specify value:

```
foreach(var x in data)
{
    var country = x.country;
    var state = x.state;
    var confirmed = x.confirmed;
}
```