# Ignore additional properties while deserializing request content

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

We are consuming requests from upstream systems. Some time, we receive request payload with additional properties which are not defined in our entity. httpcontent.ReadAsJsonAsync fails to deserialize since property is not found in our entity. We would like to handle this case gracefully, instead of throwing deserialization exception. If there are quick workarounds to ignore additional properties passed by the up stream & deserialize only with our entity definition.
We are using newtonsoft library for serialization and deserialisation.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this look like what you are trying to do? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253875/deserialize-json-with-known-and-unknown-fields

Comment: By default, Newtonsoft should not throw an exception when the JSON has extra properties that the C# class does not have.  If it is throwing, then check the settings.  There is a [`MissingMemberHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MissingMemberHandling.htm) setting which controls the behavior in this situation.  Make sure it is set to `Ignore`.  You probably have it set to `Error`.